# Fixing Kalman smoothing function

Tags: c

I am using the following smoothing function to smooth speed readings from GPS.

```
void smoothing_init()
{
    k = 0;
    kalman_init(0.0625, 32, 1.3833094, 0);
}

void kalman_init(double _q, double _r, double _p, double intial_value)
{
    q = _q;
    r = _r;
    p = _p;
    x = intial_value;
}


double smoothing_add_sample(double measurement)
{
    p = p + q;
    k = p / (p + r);
    x = x + k * (measurement - x);
    p = (1 - k) * p;
    return x;
}
```

However, sometimes this gives me smoothing values 700(the normal range is 0-150) and then going down. I guess it happens when I initialize routine with 0 but immediately receiving reading above 0 (for example 40, 50).

How can I tweak those functions to naturally prevent such spikes, but still be able to smooth data.

Comment: Why not initialize with an actual reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kalman filter is an estimator, which minimizes the variance (`p` in your code) of a system state (`x`) of a linear system. The variance `p` can be interpreted as a measure of confidence in the value of `x`.

For each time step `k` the filter performs two steps:

1. The prediction step propagates the estimate one time step ahead (in your case according to `x[k+1] = x[k] + w[k]` where `w[k]` is zero-mean Gaussian noise with variance `q`). It means here that the state variance is increased by `q`.
2. The filtering step incorporates measurement information (according to `measurement[k] = x[k] + v[k]` where `v[k]` is zero-mean Gaussian noise with variance `r`).

For classic estimation problems `p` is initialized with a very large value (little confidence in the initial value `x`). Over time `p` decreases to a value somewhere  around `q`. Note the `p` is independent of the `measurement`, so it only depends on `q,r` and `p[0]`.

So for the tweaking:

- Initialize with a large `p`, i.e. `p/r>>0`; the initialization  value of `x` does not really matter.
- The quotient `r/q` adjusts how strong the smoothing is (`r/q=0` then there's no smoothing at all).
- To choose the magnitude of `r,q`, you can assume Gaussian noise: Then you have a 95% probability the true value lies in the confidence interval of `[x-2*sqrt(p), x+2*sqrt(p)]`.